# R calculating mean of top 10 with highest value in one bracket

Tags: r

So basically what i am trying to do is to calculate what the top 10 are:

```
df_priceusd[order(df_priceusd$pop,decreasing=T)[1:10],]
```

and now i want to take the prices of the top 10 and calculate the mean of the top 10´s values to get one mean value for all of the 10.

can i somehow implement this:

```
mean(df_priceusd$mean_priceusd)
```

into my other code?

or should i go at it at another angle?

Comment: How about `mean(df_priceusd[order(df_priceusd$pop,decreasing=T)[1:10],])` ?

Comment: This gives me the following message: [1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(df_priceusd[order(df_priceusd$pop, decreasing = T)[1:10],  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: it is the "mean_priceusd" that contains the prices, if that helps :D and thank you for your response